# Convergence of the maximum of a sequence of i.i.d random variables

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

> Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with $EX_1=0$ and $EX_1^2=1$. Show that
>   $$\max\left(\frac{|X_1|}{\sqrt{n}},\frac{|X_2|}{\sqrt{n}}, \dots\right) \longrightarrow0 $$
>   in distribution.

This exercise is on the section about Central Limit Theorem on Shiryaev's book of Probability.
So, under these conditions, I know that
$$\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\longrightarrow\cal{N}(0,1)$$

in distribution, but I am not sure about how to proceed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sum_n P(|X_n| >\epsilon \sqrt n)= \sum_n P(|X_1| >\epsilon \sqrt n)=\sum_n P(X_n^{2} >\epsilon^{2}  n) <\infty$ because $E\frac {X_1^{2}} {\epsilon ^{2}} <\infty$. By Borel -Cantelli Lemma this implies that $\frac {|X_n|} {\sqrt n} \leq \epsilon$ for all $n$ sufficiently large, with probability $1$. Can you finish the proof?

Comment: We have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P\left(\frac{|X_n|}{\sqrt n} > \varepsilon\right)< \infty$, so by Borel-Cantelli, $\frac{|X_n|}{\sqrt n}<\varepsilon$ for infinitely many $n$. But this does not imply that $\frac{|X_n|}{\sqrt n}<\varepsilon$ for all but finitely many $n$, which is what you have asserted.

Comment: @Math1000 B-C Lemma tells you that the probability that $\frac {|X_n|} {\sqrt n} >\epsilon$ for infinitely many  $n$ is $0$. Take the complement of this event.

Comment: I must be missing something simple. Why is the sum convergent? The text seems to imply it's because of Markov's inequality, but that would lead to an upper bound of $\sum_n \frac{1}{n}$, which diverges.

Comment: @ClementC. For any positive random variable $Y$ with finite expectation $\sum P(Y>n) <\infty$. You don't get this from Markov's inequality.

Comment: @KaboMurphy I *was* missing something simple. Thanks (it's not Markov at all, indeed).

Comment: Ah, I mixed up $>$ and $<$ in my comment. My apologies.